# Show Image from my Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I guy 
Why this function not function???

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

            $('form#slider img.img').click(function () {

                $('div#immagini img').attr('src', $(imgArray));

            });


        });
```

I want that images of my Array to show the screen when I click on the images of my html.

HTML:

```
<form id="slider" onclick="show()">
            <img class="img" src="/images/simpson1.png"/><br>
            <img class="img" src="/images/simpson2.png"/><br>
            <img class="img" src="/images/simpson2.png"/><br>
        </form>

<div id="immagini">
        <img src="" />
    </div>
```

JS:

```
function show() {
        var imgArray = new Array();
        imgArray = new Image();
        /*-------------------------------*/
        imgArray[0] = "/images/Image1.png";
        imgArray[1] = "/images/Image2.png";
        imgArray[2] = "/images/Image3.png";

        var img = document.getElementById("slider").getElementsByClassName("img");

        switch(img)  
    {
        case 0: document.getElementById("immagini").getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = imgArray[0]; break;
        case 1: document.getElementById("immagini").getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = imgArray[1]; break;
        case 2: document.getElementById("immagini").getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = imgArray[2]; break;

    }
```

Thank 10000!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var imgArray = new Array();
        imgArray[0] = "/images/Image1.png";
        imgArray[1] = "/images/Image2.png";
        imgArray[2] = "/images/Image3.png";
            $('form#slider img.img').click(function(e) {
                var index = $(this).prevAll('img').length; // to get the length of prev images.
                $('div#immagini img').attr('src', imgArray[index]);
            });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/g8cr6/)**

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of things messy in your code.

1. The show function doesn't have a closing flower bracket.
2. You are calling onclick directly from a form, which makes no sense.

Assuming that you want to set the one image for src attribute of image tag inside div with id immagini.

I set up the following code for you.

http://jsbin.com/cotateju/1/

I recommend you first understand what you are trying to acheive.

Or if you simple want to load the three images via javascript, you don't need a switch case: You can use the below function.

```
function show() {
        var imgArray = new Array();
        imgArray = new Image();
        /*-------------------------------*/
        imgArray[0] = "http://placehold.it/350x150&text=First Image";
        imgArray[1] = "http://placehold.it/350x150&text=Second Image";
        imgArray[2] = "http://placehold.it/350x150&text=Third Image";


         document.getElementById("immagini").getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = imgArray[0]; 
         document.getElementById("immagini").getElementsByTagName('img')[1].src = imgArray[1]; 
         document.getElementById("immagini").getElementsByTagName('img')[2].src = imgArray[2];

                }
```

Comment: Your function not lauch :"Cannot set property 'src' of a null reference or undefined"